# Get some visual information of a Web page using a C++ library

Tags: c++, rendering, html

I'd like to get the x-coordinates of all elements in a Web page. That's the only thing I need. I don't want to render the page so that we can see it. All I want is just visual information as simple as the coordinates(perhaps color, font as well).

I've achieved it using the Java [CSSBox](http://cssbox.sourceforge.net/) library. Could we find any counterpart in C++?

Comment: Any opensource browser engine will do the job.

Comment: @H2CO3 I prefer a lightweight one like CSSBox. Can you please recommend one?

Comment: This is a very complicated problem. What about Javascript animation of the DOM? What about CSS animations? There are a few projects that wrap webkit into something you can use like this but its not possible to give a good answer to such a vague question.

Comment: @TerryLi Jacob Parker is right, and also rendering engines aren't lightweight (for this very reason). But here you are: WebKit, Gecko, etc.

Comment: @TerryLi web page layout is not "lightweight" if you want robust support.

Comment: Closer, but not C++: http://www.silexlabs.org/haxe/cocktail/
(http://old.haxe.org/doc/start/cpp suggests, translation into C++ is possible, though).